# How would I configure a dedicated server only to be accessible via vpn

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, dedicated-server

I have a server inside my lan. It runs owncloud and some applications for development purposes: docker, wildfly, tomcat, samba ... My workflow: I use a openvpn appliance to get inside my lan and then develop on the server.

I really like to remove the server from my flat. So I was thinking about  renting a dedicated server. How would you setup such a single machine? I do not want any other application to be accessible from the outside, except openvpn and ssh.

It is the utter most importance, that nobody except me accesses any applications/files on the server. Sadly I do not have the funds, to pay for a separate vpn/firefall server and a dedicated machine. I can afford only a single server.

Would you run a vm on the server? I simple do not know what the best practice for such scenario is.

Server: 16GB Ram, Quadcore and a lot of space

My knowledge: Linux as Server and Desktop. Ubuntu Server would be my primary choice as an host os.

**Edit 1:**

I have the following setup at home: I have a router, which forwards a single port to the openvpn appliance. When I connect to it I have full access to my network at home and to the server on which I develop. I do not need to worry about any open ports on the server because, nobody ouside my lan can access it anyway.

If I rent a single server on the internet, everybody can access it. As a production machine I would simply close all the ports except (in a webserver) 80 and 443. Then everybody could only acces the http server and that's that.

My main problem: I want to access all ports on the development machine, which resides on the internet, but I do not want any other to be able to access it. Maybe I am just thinking about it wrong...

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are worrying about. I rent a VPS (much less than a dedicated machine), and I do exactly what you are suggesting: allow access only through ssh (no root login, no password, cryptographic keys only, non-standard port). I also setup an Openvpn for accessing no the LAN itself (which LAN??? Single machine), but to use to navigate safely  over the Internet when I am away from home. I shut out all services, allow no other login (except from the console, of course). Where is the problem?

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it clarifies my questions. Maybe I am just thinking about it wrong.

Comment: iptables will help you do that.